# Regressão com parte da base

Tags: r

Tenho uma base cujo uma das coluna assume três características (forte, fraco e moderado. Como faço uma restrição na regressão para que o modelo considere apenas uma das dimensões?

Comment: O que vc quer dizer por "colocar uma restrição na regressão". Na regressão não adicionamos restrições, mas sim variáveis. O que é uma dimensão? Favor editar a pergunta com as respostas.

Comment: Talvez `lm(formula, data = subset(base, característica == "forte"))`?

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem,você tem um `dataFrame` da seguinte forma:

```
> df
   categoria    X   Y
1      Fraco  118  30
2      Fraco  484  58
3      Fraco  664  87
4      Fraco 1004 115
5      Fraco 1231 120
6      Fraco 1372 142
7      Fraco 1582 145
8   Moderado  118  33
9   Moderado  484  69
10  Moderado  664 111
11  Moderado 1004 156
12  Moderado 1231 172
13  Moderado 1372 203
14  Moderado 1582 203
15     Forte  118  30
16     Forte  484  51
17     Forte  664  75
18     Forte 1004 108
19     Forte 1231 115
20     Forte 1372 139
21     Forte 1582 140
```

Então, para aplicar ajustar um modelo de regressão à apenas uma categoria, basta você filtrar os dados. Para isso temos algumas opções.

**1ª: filtrando os dados diretamente no modelo**

```
lm(X~Y, df[df[1] == "Fraco",])
```

Aqui eu filtrei `df` para que mostrasse apenas as observações na coluna 1 que fosse igual a fraco.

**2ª: Filtrando o dataframe com o Dplyr**

```
#Carrega o pacote dplyr
library(dplyr)

#filtra a categoria de interesse
df %>% filter(categoria == "Fraco") -> df_fraco

#ajusta o modelo
lm(X~Y, df_fraco)
```

Espero ter ajudado.